# Updating tests to grade an assignment after students have submitted it in nbgrader

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbgrader

I have already released an assignment and gotten the homework submissions. From the submissions, I noticed that some of my hidden tests need to be updated.

Is it possible to update those hidden tests so that the auto-grader will run on the new tests, instead of my old tests, when grading the student submissions?

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with the same now, a year later. Inspired by [the issue here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbgrader/issues/1069), after changing the tests in the notebook file and saving these, one must again generate the version that students will receive. This can be done from the Formgrader with Generate or from the command line with `nbgrader generate_assignment`.

Afterwards, the autograder will use the new tests.